# Syntax error while using the 'using' directive

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7

I get a syntax error when I use the `System.Net` directive. I am trying to get the contents of a URL. Here is the code:

```
using System.Net;
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string reply = client.DownloadString (address);
Console.WriteLine (reply);
```

Error I see on line 1: `Syntax error, '(' expected`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the `using System.Net;` above your namespace on the very top of the editor. You have it in the scope of your method body.

Only the [**using statement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) goes there in your scope which is different.

Which in this case WebClient uses [**IDisposable**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you should be using the using statement. Example:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   string reply = client.DownloadString (address);
   Console.WriteLine (reply);
}
```